# What is a term to describe the proportion of complete to incomplete observations in a dataset?

Tags: dataset

For example, given four datapoints, one of which is null, how can I describe the completeness, or lack theereof, of the dataset?

I have been thinking about this as "density".

Is there an accepted term?

Comment: What are "null" data points? Are you talking about missing data or something else?

Comment: If you're asking about the proportion of incomplete observations (missing "column" values), the term is "missingness."

Comment: @Glen_b Yes, missing data.

Comment: @Sycorax Would "completeness" be the inverse of "missingness"?

Comment: @zadrozny Yes. (Comments must be at least 15 characters in length.)

Comment: @zadrozny please edit your question to contain the clarifications you make in comments.

Comment: For now, I'm voting to leave closed, because the edited question text doesn't yet define "null" or replace it by a more appropriate word. The question text here is quite short so will show up in search engines, so it's particularly important for it to be clear and unambiguous (even if the comments below are enlightening). But after some re-editing this should be re-openable.

Comment: @Silverfish Appreciate your striving for clarity, but at this point, not sure what's still ambiguous. I have not found a clear term on Wikipedia or elsewhere on the web, so I do think the question is useful.

Comment: What is unclear is what "null" means, which is only addressed in comments. Since the OP already agreed that "null" is "missing" why not substitute that word in the question? And then @Sycorax comment could be an answer.

Comment: _Density_ already has meaning in statistics as probability density. It's definitely not available or appropriate here. Otherwise, _proportion or percent missing_ or its complement in terms of _complete_ works fine. Sometimes, a new word is not needed: it is fine just to combine existing words. Small print: Difference between fraction of values in a dataset that are missing and fraction of observations (cases, records) that contain _any_ missing values.